# Count occurrences based on multiple columns then join to table

Tags: sql, count

I am attempting to count grades that a student may have.  Then I would like to join that to another table so that people can check it.

| student | grade |
| --- | --- |
| Student1 | A |
| Student1 | A |
| Student2 | B |
| Student2 | A |
| Student3 | C |
| Student3 | F |

I would like to count A's for each student then join it to a table I have.

I am not really sure how to start.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried a `GROUP BY` query?

Comment: I have not.  I just looked that up.  I will give that a try.  Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you truly don't know where to start then probably some SQL tutorials are the way to go while you learn the building blocks of SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include 'sub-queries' as if they're tables.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    student,
    SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS count_a_grades
  FROM
    your_table
  GROUP BY
    student
)
  AS student_grade_summary
INNER JOIN
  another_table
    ON another_table.student = student_grade_summary.student
```

You might also want to look into 'COMMON TABLE EXPRESSIONS' to tidy it up a bit.

Or `ANALYTICAL FUNCTIONS' / 'WINDOW FUNCTIONS', for cases where you want a result of an aggregate, but keeping all the original rows

Exact syntax varies from vendor to vendor, but the answer above should work everywhere.

Comment: So in theory I could have a sub query for each grade or total grades if I wanted, correct?

Comment: @slee You could. There would likely be neater options, but you could. (Open another question if you have any concrete examples in mind, where you'd like to know tidier ways of expressing a given query.)